# Wordpress - save frontend submission form field as custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, post-meta

I use WP plugin for submitting posts from frontend. It's a field builder.
Maybe it uses `wp_insert_post()` function, I really don't know.

Here I use my custom shortcode, please check here for the code:

```
function my_custom_shortcode() {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT city FROM slovak_cities" );
    
    $select = '<select name="city_field">';
    $select .= '<option value="-1">- select your city -</option>';
    
    foreach ( $results as $result ) {
        $select .= '<option value="' . str_replace( ' ', '_', strtolower( remove_accents( $result->city ) ) ) . '">' . $result->city . '</option>';
    }
    
    $select .= '</select>';
    
    return $select;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_custom_shortcode' );
```

This shortcode creates a dropdown  field in post form with many many options. All options inside are generated from database.
This everything is OK and works good.

But I need help with saving this field as custom field to post when post form is submitted.
The  element has a name attribute named "city_field". This value should be a META KEY of custom field and META VALUE should be one selected option from  element.

Can someone help me please? I know that this is related to add_post_meta() or update_post_meta() functions, but how to use them? Are there any action or filter hooks available?

Comment: Code is not enough to understand what you're doing in your project exactly. we don't know how you saved your data and if data is saved in DB or not and if it's saved then is it saved in the correct location or went somewhere else.

Comment: @VijayHardaha, sorry for misunderstanding my question, I will try to edit it and explain my problem more simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two usable hooks `wpuf_add_post_after_insert` and `wpuf_edit_post_after_update` in the plugin [documentation](https://wedevs.com/docs/wp-user-frontend-pro/developer-docs/action-hook-field/), that solved my problem:

```
function prefix_update_my_field( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['city_field'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'city_field', $_POST['city_field'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'wpuf_add_post_after_insert', 'prefix_update_my_field' );
add_action( 'wpuf_edit_post_after_update', 'prefix_update_my_field' );
```